# How to colorize input in NSTextField using NSFormatter?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nsattributedstring, nsformatter

I want to colorize the first char in the input string. It can be done easily with controlDidChange delegate method. But after adding formatter using:

```
[field setFormatter:[[MyFormatter alloc] init]];
```

NSTextField ignores any attributed strings assigned to it.

Browsing through Apple Documentation gave me the

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForObjectValue:(id)anObjects withDefaultAttributes:(NSDictionary *)aDict
```

method, but this method is never called :(

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *field;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;            
@end
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MyFormatter.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{   

    [field setAttributedStringValue:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""]];
    [field setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:YES];
    [field setDelegate:self];
    [field setFormatter:[[MyFormatter alloc] init]];
}

- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj
{  
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[field stringValue]];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    [field setAttributedStringValue:string];
}

@end
```

**MyFormatter.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyFormatter : NSFormatter 
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForObjectValue:(id)anObjects withDefaultAttributes:(NSDictionary *)aDict;
@end
```

**MyFormatter.m**

```
#import "MyFormatter.h"

@implementation MyFormatter

- (NSString *)stringForObjectValue:(id)obj
{
    return [(NSAttributedString *)obj string];
}

- (BOOL)getObjectValue:(id *)anObject forString:(NSString *)string errorDescription:(NSString **)error
{
    *anObject = [[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string] autorelease];
    return YES;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForObjectValue:(id)anObjects withDefaultAttributes:(NSDictionary *)aDict
{
    NSLog(@"This method is never called :(");
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you double-check the code to MyFormatter? Specifically, `-stringForObjectValue:` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works. You have to set `objectValue` and the formatter will convert it to an attributed string.